# Getting category posts from a certain year

Tags: posts, archives

Is there a way to get category posts from a certain year?

I know how to get all posts posted in a certain year -> [www.example.com/**year**/](http://www.example.com/**year**/)

or with months -> wwx.example.com/**year**/**month** (that's how the default archive works)

Is there a trick to get for wwx.example/**year**/**category**/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a trick to get for wwx.example.com/year/category/

The main query is open to public query variables like `year` and `cat` so without pretty permalinks you could try

```
www.example.com/?year=2022&cat=5
```

where 5 is the category id as an example and with pretty permalinks it would be redirected to

```
www.example.com/2022/?cat=5
```

Comment: Great it worked! The only thing I would add for anybody looking and this answer in the future is that "5" is the category ID...

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped Zan. I will update to make it more clear